# Isabelle: run try command without try0

Tags: isabelle

Occasionally there is a lemma, where `try0` crashes Isabelle/JEdit. Only `kill -9` on the process id works then.

When I then call `try` in the same situation, Isabelle/JEdit crashes again.

Is it possible to invoke in this situation everything from `try` without running `try0` (or otherwise omit all the proves `try0` would call)?

(I did some google searches but could not find anything relevant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [isar-ref.pdf](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013-2/dist/Isabelle2013-2/doc/isar-ref.pdf), page 267, it gives the following notes on `try0` and `try`:

- **try0** attempts to prove a subgoal using a combination of standard proof methods (auto, simp, blast, etc.). Additional facts supplied via simp:, intro:, elim:, and dest: are passed to the appropriate proof methods.
- **try** attempts to prove or disprove a subgoal using a combination of provers and disprovers (`solve_direct`, `quickcheck`, `try0`, `sledgehammer`, `nitpick`).

So if the description is complete in the Isar Reference manual, then `try` is `try0` plus two provers, `solve_direct` and `sledgehammer`, and two counterexample finders, `quickcheck` and `nitpick`.

To not run the provers of `try0`, as far as I know, you would have to run `solve_direct` and `sledgehammer` individually.

If `try0` is hanging the PIDE, then it's mostly likely going into a bad loop of some kind, where enabling `Auto Methods` in `Plugin Options / Isabelle` can also cause these loops, since it does something similar to `try0`.

There are two kind of loops that I've experienced, where I can only remember the 2nd one listed next as hanging the PIDE:

1. `simp` rule loops caused by `simp` or methods that call `simp`, such as `auto`, `force`, `fastforce`, `slowsimp`, and `bestsimp`. To stop an infinite loop, I just have to delete the command.
2. `blast` loops caused by `auto` calling `blast`. For these kind, it either happens immediately, or after I've let the command run for 5 seconds or so.

You can try to narrow down which automatic proof method is causing `try0` and `try` to hang the PIDE.

You can get a list of the `try0` methods used like this (I don't know if the list of provers it shows is complete):

```
lemma "False"
try0
(*Trying "simp", "auto", "fast", "fastforce", "force", "blast", "metis", 
  "linarith", and "presburger"...*)
oops
```

From that list, if `apply(simp)` is looping, you know there's a `simp` rule loop (or `simp` rules that take a long time to complete), which would make `auto`, `fastforce` and `force` loop, since they call `simp`.

If `auto` is looping, then it could be `simp` or `blast`, since `auto` can call each of those, so you can try `apply(blast)` to see if `blast` is the problem.

With Isabelle2013-2, for me, the hanging of the PIDE has been because of `auto`, because it calls `blast`. Supposedly, that has been fixed for the next release.

Answer (score 1):

I put this as a second answer, since it's different enough.

I was browsing through the repository changes, and that led me to the following Isabelle2013-2 ML files related to `try` and `try0` (but don't get locked in completely, because I list other files to show things are changing):

- [src/Tools/try.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/Tools/try.ML)
- [src/HOL/Tools/try0.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/HOL/Tools/try0.ML#l91)
- [src/HOL/Tools/Sledgehammer/sledgehammer_try0.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/HOL/Tools/Sledgehammer/sledgehammer_try0.ML)

The file `try.ML` gives this line of source:

```
val get_tools : theory -> tool list
```

I suppose, using ML, a person could get a list of the tools used by `try`, but if so, then it would probably correspond with the description given in the other answer from `isar-ref.pdf`.

Basically, there is `try` which calls other tools, `sledgehammer` which does its own special thing, where the use of `try0` is part of its arsenal, `solve_direct`, and then fully automatic proof methods used by `try0`, which are listed in `try0.ML`.

The majority of automatic proof methods which are listed in `try0.ML` are referenced in [isar-ref.pdf](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013-2/dist/Isabelle2013-2/doc/isar-ref.pdf) sections

- 9.3 The Simplifier [187]
- 9.4.4 Fully automated methods [211],
- 12.7 Model Elimination and Resolution [263], and
- 12.8 Algebraic reasoning via Gröbner bases [263].

Now for some changes that are coming down the pipe, taken from the latest files or changesets:

- [src/HOL/Tools/try0.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/8f4c6ef220e3/src/HOL/Tools/try0.ML#l86)
- Changeset: [got rid of 'try0' step that is now redundant](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/rev/e68fd012bbf3)
- Changeset: [implemented new 'try0_isar' semantics](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/rev/e887c0743614)

From the latest repository `try0.ML`, it gives the list of proof methods that `try0` will try. If you look at the Isabelle2013-2 `try0.ML` above, you'll see that the list given in that file is the same list of methods shown in the other answer when trying to prove `False`.

Here, there are extra automatic proof methods that aren't currently being tried with Isabelle2013-2.

```
val full_attrs = (SOME "simp", SOME "intro", SOME "elim", SOME "dest");
val clas_attrs = (NONE, SOME "intro", SOME "elim", SOME "dest");
val simp_attrs = (SOME "add", NONE, NONE, NONE);
val metis_attrs = (SOME "", SOME "", SOME "", SOME "");
val no_attrs = (NONE, NONE, NONE, NONE);

(* name * ((all_goals, run_if_auto_try), (simp, intro, elim, dest) *)
val named_methods =
  [("simp", ((false, true), simp_attrs)),
   ("auto", ((true, true), full_attrs)),
   ("blast", ((false, true), clas_attrs)),
   ("metis", ((false, true), metis_attrs)),
   ("linarith", ((false, true), no_attrs)),
   ("presburger", ((false, true), no_attrs)),
   ("algebra", ((false, true), no_attrs)),
   ("fast", ((false, false), clas_attrs)),
   ("fastforce", ((false, false), full_attrs)),
   ("force", ((false, false), full_attrs)),
   ("meson", ((false, false), metis_attrs))]
```